# Insert controller from ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have following problem. I would like to add a controller, whose name is included in the object. Object I receive from ng-repeat.

This is array:

```
  $scope.components = [
    {
      name: "box",
      controller: "BoxCtrl"
    }
    /*others components*/
  ];
```

And this is HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in components" ng-controller="{{c.controller}}">
      {{c.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I have following 
[error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=%7B%7Bc.controller%7D%7D&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined).

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ngController directive expects an instance of a controller but you give him a string.
This should do the job :

In your controller :

```
  $scope.components = [
    {
      name: "box",
      controller: BoxCtrl //Remove the quotes
    }
    /*others components*/
  ]
```

In your view :

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="c in components" ng-controller="c.controller">
      {{c.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Here is a plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/sLdZT4UPmgM7Is8SFyrb

Comment: Is there any way to close it inside nampespace?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you rephrase it ?